# I have one variable in data attribute, and pass the same variable from prop. why the {{}} template display the value from prop rather than data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In vue.js 2.0 component. The component is defined like following:

```
//html
<div id="#foo">{{ foo }}</div>

// js
Vue.component('my-foo',{
    template: '#foo',
    props:['foo'],
    data: function(){
         return {
            foo: 'from own',
         };
    }
);
```

it will only show the data from the prop:

```
<my-foo foo="from father"></my-foo>

<div id="foo">from father</div>
```

I think in the function scope, the two same variable make me confused, where is my "foo" in data. Can someone give me a detailed explain. What will happen if I have two same data. Thanks in advance.

---

coded changed, some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a prop will override a data item of the same name. Your example doesn't really show this, since your component doesn't declare any props. The attribute you are passing is just an attribute, since Vue has no reason to consider it a prop. I have no idea how you're getting the results you are getting. Note that your template has nothing inside its `{{}}`.

Here's some example code showing two components. Both declare a data item `foo`; one declares a prop `foo`. You can see what happens when each is called with and without a prop.

```js
Vue.component('my-foo', {
  template: '#foo',
  data: function() {
    return {
      foo: 'from data',
    };
  }
});

Vue.component('my-propfoo', {
  template: '#foo',
  data: function() {
    return {
      foo: 'from data',
    };
  },
  props: ['foo']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="foo"><div>-> {{foo}}</div></template>
<div id="app">
  <div>No prop declared or passed:</div>
  <my-foo></my-foo>
  <div>No prop declared, but prop passed:</div>
  <my-foo foo="from prop"></my-foo>
  <div>Prop declared, no prop passed:</div>
  <my-propfoo></my-propfoo>
  <div>Prop declared, prop passed:</div>
  <my-propfoo foo="from prop"></my-propfoo>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry,I missed  the second declare. Your write is what I mean, What makes me confused is:  if I  declare the "prop"  and have the same key in "prop"  and "data" like "foo", but one is {foo: "from prop"}, the other is {foo: "from data" },  the html will only show "from prop", why and what happened at this moment?

Comment: Ok,I think for a moment, it's just overwrite. thanks for your answer.  :)